# Programming/Verifying EPROMS with an elevated VCC

Tags: voltage, programming

Many EPROM manufacturers specify a faster programming algorithm which involves temporarily raising VCC from 5V to about 6V.

If I read with this higher VCC in place, are the outputs still limited to the 5V vcc, or does my reading circuitry need to be 6V tolerant? Similarly, going in the other direction, are the EPROM inputs (data and address) 6V tolerant?

I haven't any specific EPROM manufacturer in mind: they all do variations on this theme, but the data sheets seem to be silent on this issue. They all seem to quote a maximum logic input of VCC+0.5, with out saying -which- VCC.

Maybe I'm over thinking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I read with this higher VCC in place, are the outputs still limited to the 5V vcc, or does my reading circuitry need to be 6V tolerant?

The outputs can reach VCC of the chip if the current is low enough. In this case your VCC is 6 Volts: Your inputs must tolerate this voltage somehow.

Comment: What about going the other way? With an elevated VCC, are the TTL-level inputs allowed to go upto e.g. 6V+0.6v.